# Purpose of this expression

Tags: java

I am relatively new to Java.
I came across this statement while going through an example

```
((Integer)arg).intValue()
```

Can anybody explain this expression?

Comment: No, nobody can explain `this statement`, because it is not a statement. It is an expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `arg` is an `Object`, it is being cast to an `Integer` so that the primitive `int` value can be obtained using the `intValue()` method available on `Integer`.

In Java 5 and above, autoboxing could be utilized to simplify this to:

```
int x = (Integer)arg;
```

Comment: This statement was taken from a program that implements the Observable interface and you answer explains the statement very well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`arg` is being typecasted into an `Integer` (Java's wrapper class for `int`). The `intValue` method is then called on the `Integer`, returning the primitive `int` value.

Answer (score 1):

`(Integer) arg` basically casts integer over the argument, meaning it attempts to return the arg value in an integer format.

`intValue()` returns the value of the specified number as an int.